# Do you know any open source projects that use Java Web Services?

Tags: java, web-services, open-source

For my diploma project I am creating a tool that will study a Java project and extract the parts that declare or use Web Services in order to study the classes that communicate in this way other the network, the communication channels that are created, etc.

In order to test my tool I need some open source projects because I would like to see how it works when put in front of a real system not only some random test classes. I have searched for such projects on [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/) but I found out that many of the projects returned by the search are not completed or just unusable.

If you have worked on such a project or you just know any projects that could help me please give your input, it will be most welcome.

Basically I'm looking for projects created using Apache Axis 1.2/2, Apache CXF and SpringWS

Answer (score 2):

[soapUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/) is OS and uses web services.  It's a web service testing tool as a matter of fact.